# If $e_1, e_2, e_3$ is a positively oriented basis, prove that $e_1 \times e_2 = e_3$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:**

> Prove that if $e_1, e_2, e_3$ is a positively oriented orthonormal basis, then $e_1 \times e_2 = e_3$.

**Proof:**

According to the definition, the cross - product between two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$:  $\vec{u} \times \vec{v}$, is defined as the vector $\vec{w}$ that fulfills the following properties:

- $|\vec{w}| = |\vec{u}||\vec{v}|sin(\theta)$
- Orthogonal to both $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$
- $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}$ are positevly oriented

---

However, I'm struggling to move on from here. And I wonder whether there's another, more easy way, to prove that statement?

Thank you.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Thank you. I realized I had misread the problem. I've edited the post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two and only two vectors with norm $1$ which are orthogonal to both $e_1$ and $e_2$, which are $\pm(e_1\times e_2)$. And, by the properties that you have mentioned, only $e_1\times e_2$ is such that $\{e_1,e_2,e_1\times e_2\}$ is positively oriented. Therefore, $e_3=e_1\times e_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realized I forget to put in that it's an orthonormal basis :/

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $e_1 \times e_2$ is (defined to be) the **unique** vector satisfying the three conditions that you've written.

Note that $e_3$ also has those three conditions by hypothesis. Let us check them:

1. $|e_3| = 1 = 1 \times 1 \times \sin(\frac\pi2) = |e_1| |e_2| \sin(\theta)$,
2. $e_3$ is orthogonal to both $e_1$ and $e_2$,
3. $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$ are positively oriented.

Comment: Thank you Aryaman.